# how to make a select with double functionality in svelte

Tags: javascript, arrays, svelte, svelte-3, svelte-component

I have the following case, I have an aside component that shows the user's detail and where it shows their fullname, email and roles, the role select must show the role that already comes from the object but also must show the roles of the rolesOptions object in the options , I really don't know how to do it (detail.role are the roles that the user already brings)

codec

```js
let role = {
id:1, name:"manager",
id:2,name:'scrum',
id:3,name:'developer',
id:4,name:'tecnico'

}

let user = {
fullname:'',
email:'',
role:role

}



{#if detail.role && user.role}
           <Select label="Roles:" bind:value={detail.roles}>
             {#each (detail.roles || user.role) as item (item.id)}
               <option value={item.name}>{item.name}</option>
              {/each}
            </Select>
           
           {/if}
```

Comment: Can you add the detail object to your example? I'm not sure what is in `detail.role` and `detail.roles`.

Comment: You need to have an array-like object to iterate with `#each`, it won't work with objects. You might want to change `detail.role` and `user.role` to arrays of objects.

Answer (score 0):

I'm making a few assumptions here, but let's assume you can convert `user.role` to an array of objects and that `detail.role` follows the same structure. This would work:

```html
<script>
    let detail = {
        role: [
            { id:5, name:'product owner' },
        ]
    }
    let user = {
        fullname:'',
        email:'',
        role: [
            { id:1, name:'manager' },
            { id:2, name:'scrum' },
            { id:3, name:'developer' },
            { id:4, name:'tecnico' }
        ]
    }
    let roles = [...detail.role, ...user.role]
</script>

{#if detail.role && user.role}
    <select label="Roles:" bind:value={roles}>
        {#each (roles) as item (item.id)}
            <option value={item.name}>{item.name}</option>
        {/each}
    </select>    
{/if}
```

Comment: Hi Julio, can I show you the internal code?